# What is this flying insect?

Tags: entomology, species-identification

This insect was captured in Australia near Canberra. It has a very hard exoskeleton and is over an inch long. It seems to have 6 wings - 2 large pairs and one very small pair. I did not see a stinger - however I have no idea.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this is the Hairy Flower Wasp, *[Scolia soror](http://gvcocks.homeip.net/Hymenoptera/Scoliidae/scolia_soror.htm)*. I don't know what you mean when you refer to six wings, however. Like all other wasps, this species has four wings.

Comment: he might be referring to the beetle-like carapace as another set of wings.